# Replacing part of a string with countdown numbers using the command sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, numeric-data

I have a string: `TestTest12312313`. I would like to replace the number `13` in this string with countdown numbers `-1,-2,-3,-4, ....` using the command `sed`, so the output is as follows:

```
TestTest123123-1
TestTest123123-2
TestTest123123-3
TestTest123123-4
.....
.....
.....
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting stuck somewhere? Google would take you right to an easy way to do this.

Comment: Im stuck, i dont know how to do this i cant find nothing in google

Comment: All you need is the `sed` command which is used for replacing strings. Google it with how to replace strings and try some of what you've read. If you're still getting stuck, edit your question with what you have tried and where it isn't working.

Comment: is the number of characters is fixed?

Comment: Much easier to do in awk for example than in sed - e.g. `awk -v s='TestTest12312313' -v n=5 'BEGIN{sub(/13$/,"-",s); for(i=1;i<n;i++) print s i}'`

Comment: Is the string in a file? Does the file have multiple lines? Do you need to do this for every line? Do the numbers always end with ``13``? or do you want to replace the last two characters, no matter what they are? (Do you care if they are not numbers?) Do you want to output four lines, or do you mean 1, 2, 3, …, and so on? Do you want to output a list of strings until your computer runs out of memory, or do you want to go up to some number (1, 2, 3, …, 13 and stop)? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Have the following code in a file

```
INPUT=$1
CONTENT=`echo "$INPUT" | cut -c1-14`
COUNT=`echo "${INPUT#"$CONTENT"}"`
for i in $(seq 1 "$COUNT")
do
        echo "$CONTENT-$i"
done
```

Run the script with runtime input as below:

```
sh file.sh TestTest12312313
TestTest123123-1
TestTest123123-2
TestTest123123-3
TestTest123123-4
TestTest123123-5
TestTest123123-6
TestTest123123-7
TestTest123123-8
TestTest123123-9
TestTest123123-10
TestTest123123-11
TestTest123123-12
TestTest123123-13
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
string='TestTest12312313' 
printf '%s\n' ${string%??}-{1..100}
```

The *`${parameter%word}`* is [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and deletes the last two characters from its parameter.

---

At above you can adjust the 100 with any number you want to continue print.

if you would like to repeat to printing the *string* with exactly last two digits your *string* ends with it, you could do as following:

```
string='testString07'
eval printf '%s\\n' ${string%??}-{1..${string:((${#string}-2))}}
testString-01
testString-02
testString-03
testString-04
testString-05
testString-06
testString-07
```

This `${string:((${#string}-2))}` syntax is coming from [Shell Sub-String Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) *`${parameter:startPosition:length}`* (if *`length`* omitted it will return from *`startPOsition`* to the end.) where *startPosition* is `((${#string}-2))`, that returning the length in characters of its `string` as *parameter* minus 2.

Well, that would be also simplified to:

```
eval printf '%s\\n' ${string%??}-{1..${string#${string%??}}}
```

---

if it's a file not a single string, I would suggest to use `awk` here as following:

```
awk -F'..$' '{print $1"-"NR}' infile
```

this is setting the awk's field separator with two last characters of each line (it's `..$` a regex that matches only two characters at the end of line), and then we are printing the first field and its **N**umber of **R**ecord delimited with hyphen. That would be shortened to:

```
awk -F'..$' '$0=$1"-"NR' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
$ echo 'TestTest12312313' | awk '{ s = substr($0, 1, length - 2); while (1) printf("%s-%d\n", s, ++n) }'
TestTest123123-1
TestTest123123-2
TestTest123123-3
TestTest123123-4
TestTest123123-5
TestTest123123-6
TestTest123123-7
TestTest123123-8
TestTest123123-9
(etc., forever...)
```

The `awk` code extracts the input line (your string) and removes the last two characters, storing the result in the variable `s`. It then goes into an infinite loop which prints this string along with an ever incrementing integer in the format shown above.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the following one liner:

```
$ a=1; for i in $(sed 's/13$//' inputfile);do echo "${i}-$((a++))"; done
TestTest123123-1
TestTest123123-2
TestTest123123-3
TestTest123123-4
TestTest123123-5
TestTest123123-6
```